# Where can I download Visual Foxpro? MSDN?

Tags: msdn, visual-foxpro, foxpro

We have a legacy application written in Visual FoxPro I just inherited.  We are unable to figure out where to download Visual FoxPro.  We have an MSDN subscription which I have been told should get my a license for it as needed but I literally cannot find the download.

Comment: FoxPro 9.0 downloads: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=90&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0 (this will take you to the public page, you'll have to log in to actually download). If you need 7 or 8 and still can't find links let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A search for "FoxPro" on the MSDN subscriber downloads page yielded 7 results for me. Apparently, Visual FoxPro 7, 8, and 9 are available from the Visual Studio Professional level.

More precisely, FoxPro 9 is availble for these subscriber levels:

```
Available to these Subscription Levels:
VS Pro with MSDN (VL)
VS Ultimate with MSDN (BizSpark Administrator)
VS Ultimate with MSDN (BizSpark Member)
VS Ultimate with MSDN (MPN)
VS Ultimate with MSDN (MPN)
VS Ultimate with MSDN (NFR FTE)
VS Ultimate with MSDN (Retail)
VS Ultimate with MSDN (VL)
DreamSpark Premium
DreamSpark Standard
MCT Developer Software & Services
MCT Software & Services
VS Premium with MSDN (MPN)
VS Premium with MSDN (MPN)
VS Premium with MSDN (Retail)
VS Premium with MSDN (VL)
VS Pro with MSDN (Retail)
```

Source: MSDN Subscriber site (that link is protected, so linking is pointless)

Comment: I was unaware you had to search for it on this special downloads page, thanks.